# Scikit-learn tutorial gives me a depreciation error, how to update?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deprecated, deprecation-warning

I acquired a copy of *Mastering Machine Learning with scikit-learn*, and I began working through it. However, it seems that a good amount of the code is now outdated.

The first code snippet in the book,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
X = [[6], [8], [10], [14],   [18]]
y = [[7], [9], [13], [17.5], [18]]
plt.figure()
plt.title('Pizza price plotted against diameter')
plt.xlabel('Diameter in inches')
plt.ylabel('Price in dollars')
plt.plot(X, y, 'k.')
plt.axis([0, 25, 0, 25])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Ran just fine. However, when I moved on to the second one:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
# Training data
X = [[6], [8], [10], [14],   [18]]
y = [[7], [9], [13], [17.5], [18]]
# Create and fit the model
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, y)
print 'A 12" pizza should cost: $%.2f' % model.predict([12])[0]
```

It gave me an error:

```
 A 12-inch pizza should cost: $%.2f
 /home/dave/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:386: DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
   DeprecationWarning)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "002----Chapter2-B.py", line 11, in <module>
     print ("A 12-inch pizza should cost: $%.2f") % model.predict([12])[0]
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

When it *should* have given me this:

```
 A 12" pizza should cost: $13.68
```

Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: Surely the textbook should specify the version of scikit-learn it is written for...?

Comment: I'm using Anaconda, I can't change the versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
print ("A 12-inch pizza should cost: $%.2f" % model.predict(np.array([12]).reshape(1, -1)[0]))
```

I used `reshape(1,-1)` for passing 2d array to `predict` function.

Comment: That gave me an `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing` error.

Comment: sorry, i missed ')' at the end

Comment: write 'import numpy as np' at the fisrt line of file

Comment: Wait, that was wrong. It's still giving me a `DeprecationWarning` error, even though it now gives me the correct answer afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code:

```
print('A ' + diameter + ' inch pizza should cost: $%.2f' % model.predict([d] [0]))
```

The [documentation pages](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.libsvm.predict.html) give more details about the `predict` method:

```
sklearn.svm.libsvm.predict()
```

Parameters:

```
X : array-like, dtype=float, size=[n_samples, n_features]
```